# Reactive Form (Cannot Read property error of null)

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

Error:
Cannot read property errors of null in form group.

I am creating a reactive form with some validation but i'm getting this error.Below is my whole form control

```
  <div class="container mt-5">
<form
  [formGroup] = 'loginForm'
  (ngSubmit) = 'onSubmit()'
  >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>User Name</label>
    <input
      type="text" class="form-control"
      placeholder="Enter User Name"
      formControlName = "userName"
      [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (
                                  loginForm.get('userName').dirty &&
                                  !loginForm.get('userName').valid
      )}"
      >
    <span class="invalid-feedback">
      <span *ngIf = "loginForm.get('firstName').errors?.required">
        Please Enter User Name.
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Password"
      formControlName = "password"
      >
  </div>
  <button
    type="submit"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    [disabled] = "!loginForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>

{{loginForm.valid}}
```

Comment: How have you defined loginForm?

Comment: I mean.. shouldn’t this : loginForm.get('firstName') be userName and not firstName..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code, the possible reason for this error seems like you are accessing the firstName formcontrol when it is not defined in the loginForm.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have gonna wrong with the formControlName, either it is not added in .ts file or by mistake you have mentioned '**firstName**' in the error span

1. Replace ***firstName*** with ***userName*** in the error span

Please replace this code -

```
<span *ngIf = "loginForm.get('firstName').errors?.required">
    Please Enter User Name.
  </span>
```

With

```
<span *ngIf = "loginForm.get('userName').errors?.required">   // Here is the change
    Please Enter User Name.
  </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG, one hour working on it, realized I had

```
  this.ContactInfoFG.get('phoneNumberFG') as FormGroup;
```

instead of

```
 this.contactInfoFG.get('phoneNumberFG') as FormGroup;
```

Just check the characters for this issue nothing else!

Your solutions helped as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update @i-stand-with-israel though I had it that way purposely to show 'C' and 'c' in bold.